# Epson Perfection V200 photo scanner

Tags: scanner

I cannot get an Epson Perfection V200 Photo scanner to work on Ubuntu 16.04. It works fine on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
robert@saaz:~$ lsusb | grep -i Epson
Bus 001 Device 091: ID 04b8:012e Seiko Epson Corp. GT-F670 [Perfection V200 Photo]

robert@saaz:~$ scanimage -L
device `epkowa:usb:001:091' is a Epson (unknown model) flatbed scanner
device `epkowa:interpreter:001:091' is a Epson (unknown model) flatbed scanner
```

(This took ages...)

```
robert@saaz:~$ sane-find-scanner -q | grep -i Epson
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [EPSON], product=0x012e [EPSON Scanner]) at libusb:001:091
```

In /etc/sane.d/dll.conf, I enabled the epkowa configuration file and added `usb 0x04b8 0x012e` to /etc/sane.d/epkowa.

I did install Epson's proprietary drivers.  Still Image Scan just says it "could not send command to scanner". It's not a permissions issue, it neither works as regular user (member of the scanner group) nor as root.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a hardware problem. I had the scanner attached via a USB switch to easily share it between different computers. It did not work with a USB3 port (limited cable length as per the USB spec), but as soon as I moved it to the USB2 port, everything worked.